# async function returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have an async function that should return a geocode value:

```
async function latlng(place){
//var str;
return googleMapsClient.geocode({
    address: place
}).asPromise()
.then((response) => { response.json.results[0].geometry.location
    /*str = response.json.results[0].geometry.location;
    return str;*/
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
}
```

When I call it, it returns nothing, but it has a value

I'm calling:

```
(async function(){
    //location start
    start = await data.latlng(req.body.start);
    //location end
    end = await data.latlng(req.body.end);
})();
```

Why does it return nothing if it's all fine in the function? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to take advantage of arrow functions with implicit returns, but you're using the syntax for arrow functions with statements. I'd [read up on arrow functions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you're confused about which version to use when

Comment: If your using `async`, why are you then using `.then`?

Comment: Why have you commented out the code with the `return` in the `then` callback? It would work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `async / await`.. That's great, but for some reason inside your function you decide not to bother.. :)

Also there is no point in catching error in your latlng function, it doesn't make sense as your `start` / `end` surely require both to have been valid..

Here is the latlng function simplified, using `async / await` for what it was meant for.

```
async function latlng(place){
  const response =
    await googleMapsClient.geocode({ address: place }).asPromise();
  return response.json.results[0].geometry.location;
}
```